# jQuery: setting ckeditor baseurl

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

i'm using ckEditor together with its own jQuery adapter and i'd like to define the editor's baseUrl in order that it will show images in the html.

here's my code - unfortunately doesnt work:

```
    var txt = $("textarea");
    txt.ckeditor();
    var editor = txt.ckeditorGet();
    editor.baseurl = "/myweb1/test/";
```

any ideas what's wrong?

thanks

Comment: Are you getting any JavaScript errors with that or is it just the fact that the images are not showing?

Comment: Harry has answered it for me :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The configuration property which you are looking for is actually [ckeditor.config.baseHref](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.baseHref)

You can pass in configuration options through the ckeditor() initializer like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( 'textarea' ).ckeditor({baseHref : "http://www.google.com/"});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">
&lt;img src="intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif" /&gt;
</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

You can also do it more dynamically like so:

```
txt = $( 'textarea' ).ckeditor();
txt.ckeditorGet().config.baseHref="http://www.google.com/"
```

Some more info can be found here - http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor_for_jQuery